# Android progress bar in ListView loading

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I want to add in my app `ListView`, inside `LinearLayout` that when is loading instead of list has progress bar. This is something similar like in system app, where you can manage your apps.

I found some info about it, but none was ok. The one, that seems the best was saying to create two layouts (one with progress bar and another with ListView) and then in `onPreExecute()` (I am using `AsyncTask` for this) show the progress bar. Then in `onPostExecute()` hide it and that's all.

I was trying to implement it, but I have ScrapView error, and no more info, how it can be done.

So, my question is, how would you recommend me to do it? **I don't want any progress dialog.**

**EDIT:**

This are fragments of my code, showing what I've done so far:

*TestActivity.java*

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mylist_layout);
            wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordsList);

            //...
    }

        private class AsyncDBDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
                LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        refreshList();//upload of contetn and set of adapter
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    wordList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

    private void refreshList() {
            //List content download into Cursor - adapterCursor 
            //...

            wordList.setAdapter(adapterCursor);
        }
```

word_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wordsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Two extra things:

- in `onResume()` there is call for AsyncTask to be execute;
- in `mylist_layout.xml` in place where should list be there is include which includes into this layout `word_list.xml` layout

Other things:

- I don't want to use progress dialog, because it doesn't fit into my needs, and I don't find it's look good for my purpose. I would like to replace the list, not to ad anything more.
- ListFragment seems quite ok, but I think that there may be other better, or easier solutions to achive what I want.

I am doing app Android 2.2/2.3 compatible, I forget to mention, so if some thing isn't inside `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, than I won't use it.

Comment: Please share what you have done...

Comment: Why dont you want to use Progress Dialogs?

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah Code added

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ListFragment`. Use `setListShown()` with `true`/`false` to hide/show a loader instead of a list.